# Did I expose myself to information-theft via possible malware on iPad by opening an e-mail in Safari?

Tags: email, ipad, malware

I received an email from cdhhospitals.org/upload.htm and opened it. I immediately was redirected to a waiting screen. I immediately closed the Safari app.

I tried to track this site down and the search states that this site may damage your computer.

Did I expose myself to information-theft or anything alike?

Answer (score 5):

It appears the site is distributing malware. If you opened the page on your computer you should first install a good antivirus/antimalware program, try [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx) which is good and free. If it was on your iPad (as your tag suggests) there's probably a bit less cause for alarm as there is currently no known virus which can infect an iPad.

Next it's probably a good idea to change all of your passwords, most importantly your AppleID as it stores your confidential information and credit card data. You can manage your apple id [here.](https://appleid.apple.com/)

Comment: Does this actually do anything on Macs, or is it only a Windows problem?

Comment: Depends on the malware. A virus can be written for mac just like it can be written for windows.

Comment: My question was supposed to refer to the cdhhospitals.org thingie.

Comment: Without downloading the malware myself, removing my own antivirus software in order do so and thus potentially exposing my own computer to infection in order to analyse it, I cannot tell you. All I can tell you is that the site is distributing malware of some kind.

Comment: It is OK to say you don't know.  I was wondering if perhaps someone here did know the details about this particular site.